# Check variable value is in array or not Django

Tags: python, django, arrays, compare

Hi can anybody tell me how can i check the variable value is in array or not
like i have

```
variable = 17.40
array = [14.40,14.12,45.50.....]
```

need to check the variable value is present or not

edited
i have try the following but it doesnot work

```
scoremx = [19,18,17]
style_score=score.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
if style_score.style_quiz_score in scoremx: 

it goes in else cxondition but it has the 19 value in database
```

Comment: Does `style_quiz_score` is an integer ?

Comment: containing float and int values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if int(style_score.style_quiz_score) in scoremx:
    pass
```

You can't compare an int and a float.
And you should make like this :

```
if 17 <= style_score.style_quiz_score < 20:
   pass
```

Comment: 'you can`t compare an int and a float' - wrong; in Python you can check if any element is in list, for example: if 'test' in [1, 2.4, 'test']: print 'ok'

Answer (score 1):

```
if variable in array:
    #do something
```

Comment: i have try the following but it doesnot work   scoremx = [19,18,17]
                        style_score=score.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
if style_score.style_quiz_score in scoremx:     it goes in else cxondition but it has the 19 value in database

Comment: what is type of style_score.style_quiz_score?

Comment: containing float and int values